# как вывести другие колонки?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

в данный момент у меня выводиться "id", но мне еще надо получить несколько параметров, таких как "image","name" и добавить сюда div class, как мне это реализовать???

```
 <?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return Html::a(Html::encode($model->id), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    },
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

Создаем `view` с выводом модели (например `_item`), тут уже можно добавить `div` и прочее оформление.

```
<div class="item-test">
    <?= Html::encode($model->name); ?>     
    <?= Html::a(Html::encode($model->id), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]); ?>
</div>
```

Теперь изменяем `ListView`:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_item'
]); ?>
```

Таким образом модель будет выводиться по `view` `_item`.

Из [документации по yii\widgets\ListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html): `$itemView` - The **name of the view for rendering each data item**, or a callback (e.g. an anonymous function) for rendering each data item.